# Why aren't the Path Options working in Photoshop CC 2019?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, path, cc-2019

I can't access the **Path Options** in Photoshop CC2019. 
What can cause these to be disabled?

[image]

[image: strong text]

Answer (score 1):

Check you Photoshop `Performance` setting: `Path Options` only work with `Use Graphics Processor` option turned on.

- If the option is disabled, turn it on and restart PS;
- If the option is greyed out your GPU isn't supported by Photoshop and  I guess the only thing you can do is to get a more modern PC;

[image]